# "Unable to resolve template based identifier X" - Call a template parameter class's method from template class (C++)

Tags: c++, templates, subclass

I have these objects we'll call "`MyGroup`"s.  `MyGroup` subclasses `BaseGroup`.  Being a real-time system, we don't have the luxury of dynamic memory allocation, so we have an `ObjectPool` that allocates a certain number of objects of a given type.  So in this case I have say 10 `MyGroup` objects allocated.

Now - I want to store these groups in a Key-Value map.  So I created a `FiniteMap` template class to create a generic map of a given size, that can store a given type of object.

My `GroupList` class subclasses `FiniteMap`, still allowing parameters `<G, S>`, since I don't know which subclass of `BaseGroup` I want to store in my GroupList.

The `BaseGroup::createGroup()` method is pure virtual, so it's implemented in `MyGroup`.

So - the problem is, in the line marked with `// ***`, I'm getting one of the two following in compilation: Either a warning: `Unable to resolve template based identifier createGroup`, or if I actually call the `getOrCreateGroup()` method, an error: `cannot call member function 'virtual MyGroup* MyGroup::createGroup(unsigned int) without object`.

The GroupList object is instantiated in main logic:

```
GroupList<MyGroup, 10> myGroupList;
```

Any ideas?

I have these template classes:

```
template <class T, unsigned int S>
class FiniteMap
{
    // class to implement an array of these types of structures.
    // Contains methods for put, remove, get, etc.
    struct Entry
    {
        int key;
        T* pObject;
        bool inUse;
        Entry() : key(0), pObject(NULL), inUse(false) {}
    }
}

template <class G, unsigned int S>
class GroupList : public FiniteMap<G, S>
{
    // ...
    G* getOrCreateGroup(unsigned int groupNumber)
    {
       G* pGroup = this->get(groupNumber);
       if (pGroup == NULL)
       {
          pGroup = G::createGroup(groupNumber);  // ***
          if (pGroup == NULL)
          {
             // handle error
          }
       }
       return pGroup;
    }
}

class BaseGroup
{
public:
    virtual BaseGroup* createGroup(unsigned int groupNumber) = 0;

protected:
    unsigned int _groupNumber;
}

class MyGroup : BaseGroup
{
public:
    virtual MyGroup* createGroup(unsigned int groupNumber)
    {
        MyGroup* g = MyGroupPool.New();   // Object pool allocation
        if (g == NULL)
        {
            // handle error
        }
        else
        {
            g->_groupNumber = groupNumber;
        }
        return g;
    }
}
```

Comment: Partially fixed it by changing the `GroupList` class definition to:
`template <BaseGroup, unsigned int S> class GroupList : public FiniteMap<BaseGroup, S>`, and changing all the `G`'s to `BaseGroup` in `GroupList`.

But now I'm getting that I can't call `createGroup()` without an object.  But I don't know which subclass of `BaseGroup` I want to create in `getOrCreateGroup`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call

```
G::createGroup();
```

because `createGroup` is not static neither are you inherited from `G`.

Did you mean to make `createGroup` static? (also non-virtual) It is not clear to me why this is virtual.

Comment: It's virtual because I want to be able to create different subclasses of `BaseGroup`, and each will need to use his own Object Pool allocator.  Thus I need to make `createGroup` virtual, and force each subclass to define it.

I would love to make it static, but I get an error when I try to make it virtual and static.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the `GroupList` class is instantiated in my main logic:

`GroupList<MyGroup, 10> myGroupList;`

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you don't have an instance of `MyGroup` available to call `myGroupObject->createGroup(...)`. Though because `createGroup` does not rely on any members, you should make it static instead of virtual

Answer (score 0):

Well this is how I solved the problem.  Not sure if it was the best way to do it or not.

Basically, I made a `createGroup` pure virtual method in `GroupList`, and then created new `MyGroupList` class that handled creating the `MyGroup` objects.

```
template <class T, unsigned int S>
class FiniteMap
{
    // class to implement an array of these types of structures.
    // Contains methods for put, remove, get, etc.
    struct Entry
    {
        int key;
        T* pObject;
        bool inUse;
        Entry() : key(0), pObject(NULL), inUse(false) {}
    }
}

template <class G, unsigned int S>
class GroupList : public FiniteMap<G, S>
{
    // ...
    G* getOrCreateGroup(unsigned int groupNumber)
    {
       G* pGroup = this->get(groupNumber);
       if (pGroup == NULL)
       {
          pGroup = G::createGroup(groupNumber);  // ***
          if (pGroup == NULL)
          {
             // handle error
          }
       }
       return pGroup;
    }

private:
    virtual G* createGroup(unsigned int groupNumber) = 0;
}

template <unsigned int S>
class MyGroupList : public GroupList<MyGroup, S>
{
public:
    virtual MyGroup* createGroup(unsigned int groupNumber)
    {
        MyGroup* g = MyGroupPool.New();
        return  g;  // may be NULL if unable to allocate
    }
}


class BaseGroup
{
public:
    // stuff

protected:
    unsigned int _groupNumber;
}

class MyGroup : BaseGroup
{
public:
    // some other stuff
}
```